# Integrate multiple LDAP user data into one LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, opends

I want to integrate mutiple LDAP (AD, OpenDS, OpenLDAP etc) user data into one LDAP (OpenDS).  Is there any tool which does it?  Also, I need my LDAP to be in sync with all other LDAPs so that any change in user info will be reflected in my LDAP as well.

If there isn't a tool for it, can it be achieved through coding?  I am new to LDAP and any guidance will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most LDAP servers can participate in federations so as to do what you want. Have a look at your OpenDS documentation, federation section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what most Metadirectory tools are designed to do.

There are two approaches.

1) Sync all data and changes from all the various sources into a central LDAP repository. The Metadirectory itself.

2) Federate or have some kind of proxy that allows a consolidated view.  Often these are called Virtual Directories.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at OpenIDM open source project at openidm.forgerock.org, which can be used to synchronize entries between different services, including LDAP servers.
OpenIDM has in production deployments with 2 ways synchronization between AD and OpenDJ (OpenDJ is OpenDS continuation as an open source project. Upgrade from OpenDS is straightforward).

Kind regards,
Ludo